# Corporate URL without subdomain for salesforce site pages

Tags: force.com-sites, experience-cloud, site.com, custom-domain

I have a domain related question.

So my client wants to use their company website on the community site.

Client website is like: MyCompany.com
Our community url is like: MyCompany.my.site.com/communityname/s

The expectation is to have : **MyCompany.com/communityname/s**

The website MyCompany.com is active and it has its own functionality.

We used domains, and DNS, CNAME entries. I had to use a subdomain to not disturb the main website. I have successfully created masking, but it looks like this.
**community.MyCompany.com/communityname/s**
I had to use subdomain.

I thought of creating domain record for **MyCompany.com** in our domains and a DNS record to point to https://MyCompany.com. OrgID18.live.siteforce.com/, I am afraid this will completely take over the existing website. We dont want that, **MyCompany.com** has to stay as **MyCompany.com**. And a click on, **MyCompany.com/communityname/s** has to bring the user to salesforce pages.

Now the question is :
Is there a way to make site url look like : clientname.com/communityname/s  without using a subdomain?

Comment: You've answered your own question - out of the box, SF requires DNS CNAME to point to the custom domain. If you can't do that with top-level domain, then subdomain is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. I will use subdomain, I just needed to confirm my understanding.